# Are C functions bad style in Objective-C interfaces?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

I declare an interface with some functions and some methods. Instead of declaring:
`-(void)foo;`
`+(void)bar;`

I declare:
`-(void)foo;`
`void bar();`

I think it's fine. The compiler thinks it's fine. Do other programmers also think it's fine?

Answer (score 2):

Concerns when choosing a C function or a static method: (from the top of my head)

- Name collisions: Prefer static methods.
- Functionality: Names are like roads, they tell you where you are and where you can go. If the code is related to something else you should make it a class method. Even when it is a garbage dump of unrelated methods (`xxxUtils` classes). Otherwise use a C function.
- Locality: Prefer static methods as a way to group code in higher level units (because this is easier to see and understand from 30,000 feet).
- Typing: A C function requires less of it. CGPointMake convenience function wouldn't be so convenient with more typing.
- Linking: A bad call to a C function is seen before runtime.
- Global state: Not a choosing criteria, but worth saying that in a OOP language, the output of C functions and class methods should depend on their inputs only. Touching global state goes against encapsulation, hides dependencies, makes code harder to understand, etc.
- Overloading: C functions can be overloaded when tagged with `__attribute__((overloadable))`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Good and objective. Now I want one that's good and subjective to complement it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the point of the question. You can similarly declare them all together:

```
 -(void)foo;
 +(void) bar;
 void bar();
```

All are legal in objective C and can co-exist with the same name as they are different entities (instance method, class method, C function). You can call `void bar()` from either of the former without issue, but not v/v as void bar() doesn't get passed a reference to `self`.

If the question is rather an issue of style, I would declare C functions separately from the @interface as they are not Objective-C.

With recent versions of Clang there is no need to declare these at all if they are not for public use...

*update*

Having read @Jano's answer, I now understand the point of the question a little more: why choose a class method over a function where either can achieve the same result (neither have access to `self`).  These days I tend to always use the class method, it just seems to make sense in an obj-C context. Jano's answer seems pretty exhaustive as to why.

Comment: It's purely a matter of style yes. I would probably declare them outside the @interface but in the same header file.

If they're private I would declare them `static` in the source file of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a matter of USED-TO.

I would go for Objective-C style of methods unless I need some functions that are only available in C like pow().

Even if you want to add a C method, I feel it should be in a separate file, as `AllCMethods.c` It will be easier to recall, remember, use all obj-c methods and C-methods.